Limit access to just one API endpoint of backend application from a consumer application and restricting other endpoints access
I have two consumer apps for my backend application developed in springboot 3.x and java 17. My frontend (FE) consumer application has access to all API endpoints while for other, i want to give access to just 1 API endpoint (/usr/abc/1) based upon authentication.
Here is the code i added my securityconfig.java file in my backend application. But, it works in a way that it give access to both the applications for all the endpoints if i keep the order of beans in a following way. But if i swap the orders then it restricts my FE application access for all the endpoints which i don't want but work for 2nd application where i get access to just one endpoint (/usr/abc/1) not for other endpoints.
Can someone suggest what went wrong with this ?
    @Bean
    @Order(1)
    SecurityFilterChain abcFilter1(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
         CorsConfiguration cc = new CorsConfiguration();
         cc.setAllowedHeaders(List.of("Authorization", "Cache-Control", "Content-Type"));
         cc.setAllowedOrigins(List.of("*"));
         cc.setAllowedMethods(List.of("GET", "POST","OPTIONS")); 
         cc.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:3000","example.com/“));
         cc.setAllowCredentials(true);
         cc.setExposedHeaders(List.of("Authorization"));

         http.cors(Customizer.withDefaults()).csrf().disable();
         http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.NEVER);
         http.apply(AadResourceServerHttpSecurityConfigurer.aadResourceServer())
            .and()
            .authorizeHttpRequests()
            .requestMatchers("/", "/health").permitAll()  
            .anyRequest().authenticated();

    return http.build();
   }

   @Bean
   @Order(2)
   public SecurityFilterChain abcFilter2(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.cors(Customizer.withDefaults()).csrf().disable();
    http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.NEVER);
    http.apply(AadResourceServerHttpSecurityConfigurer.aadResourceServer())
            .and()
            .authorizeHttpRequests()
            .requestMatchers("/usr/abc/1").authenticated()
            .requestMatchers( "/","/health").permitAll()  
            .anyRequest().denyAll();

    return http.build();
   }

i want to give access to 2nd consumer application to just 1 API endpoint only (/usr/abc/1) based upon authentication while complete access (based upon authentication) of all endpoints.

Since you don't restrict access to the SecurityFilterChain via HttpSecurity#securityMatchers both filter chain feel responsible for all endpoints. That being said, the fist one in line wins. So what you have to do is:

Restrict access to the filter chains
Give the filter an order
(optional): you can omit the securityMatchers restrictions for the last filter in line when you wanna set this one as default, so that any requests not handled by a filter before will end up here

This will then be your config for SecurityFilterChain:
@Bean
@Order(10)
public SecurityFilterChain abcFilter1(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.cors(Customizer.withDefaults()).csrf().disable();
    http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.NEVER);

    http.apply(AadResourceServerHttpSecurityConfigurer.aadResourceServer()).and()

        .securityMatchers(matchers -> matchers.requestMatchers("/usr/abc/1"))

        .authorizeHttpRequests()
        .anyRequest().authenticated();

    return http.build();
}

@Bean
@Order(20)
public SecurityFilterChain abcFilter2(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

     CorsConfiguration cc = new CorsConfiguration();
     cc.setAllowedHeaders(List.of("Authorization", "Cache-Control", "Content-Type"));
     cc.setAllowedOrigins(List.of("*"));
     cc.setAllowedMethods(List.of("GET", "POST","OPTIONS")); 
     cc.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:3000","example.com/"));
     cc.setAllowCredentials(true);
     cc.setExposedHeaders(List.of("Authorization"));

     http.cors(Customizer.withDefaults()).csrf().disable();
     http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.NEVER);

     http.apply(AadResourceServerHttpSecurityConfigurer.aadResourceServer()).and()

        .authorizeHttpRequests()
        .requestMatchers("/", "/health").permitAll()  
        .anyRequest().authenticated();

    return http.build();
}


With two filter chains, the sequence of execution matters, hence the @Order annotation. The key is to ensure each filter chain operates independently to avoid undesired interactions.
If one filter chain has broader permissions and is executed before a more restrictive one, it can override the more restrictive permissions, causing unintended access issues.
Try the below code and give it a chance:
@Bean
@Order(1) // Highest priority
SecurityFilterChain frontendSecurity(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
        .csrf().disable()
        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
        .authorizeHttpRequests()
        .anyRequest().authenticated(); // Allow access to all endpoints with authentication
    
    return http.build();
}

@Bean
@Order(2) // Lower priority
SecurityFilterChain limitedAccessSecurity(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
        .csrf().disable()
        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
        .authorizeHttpRequests()
        .requestMatchers("/usr/abc/1").authenticated() // Restricted endpoint
        .anyRequest().denyAll(); // Deny all other requests
    
    return http.build();
}


With your solution no requests will ever hit the limitedAccessSecurity filter chain, since all requests are already handled by frontendSecurity .

@Slevin Well I'm not an expert here, I'm just trying to help. But aren't both the security chains separated and individually prioritized based on the bean method?

If you don't know how Spring Security's concept of SecurityFilterChains works please don't confuse others. Without relying on HttpSecurity#securityMatchers, @Order will not have the effect you intended. You should only answer when you know what you are doing.  Wrong answers are not helpful at all, although I'll give you that you wanted to help.
